# How to make custom table cell with repeating image pattern in Wikipedia?

Tags: cell, mediawiki

My goal is to be able to make a table cell in Wikipedia have a hatch pattern instead of a solid color.

This is relatively easy to do in html since the background image you give an html table cell will tile to fill its space, you can just give it a pattern image.

I am struggling with making this work for wiki markup though.  In fact I can't even get this html to work in wikipedia because I don't know how to get a background image in a table cell.

My ultimate goal is to make a template that I can use in a wiki markup table to put a hatch pattern for that cell.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the css used on the wiki you could try setting the style - see this [article for more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help%3aTable#Style_classes)

The you could create a css class with the appropriate background image